# SQL N-M relationship gets the most producible products with the least material

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I create a difficult scenario to increase my troubleshooting skills.
In my example I want to make as many different products as possible with the same (as little different) materials.

I create the Table like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_test](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REFProduct] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REFMaterial] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I filled it with Random Data while REFProduct and REFMaterial 0< int <30

I managed to determine the SQL to get the Products with the fewest Materials:

```
SELECT COUNT(REFMaterial) AS ProductMaterials
FROM Table_test
GROUP BY REFProduct
ORDER BY ProductMaterials
```

Sample Datas:

```
|ID|REFMaterial|REFProdukt|
|--|-----------|----------|
|1 |6          |13        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|2 |5          |28        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|3 |2          |24        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|4 |29         |14        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|5 |18         |15        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|6 |8          |16        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|7 |2          |26        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|8 |11         |23        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|9 |3          |25        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|10|7          |27        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|11|4          |4         |
|--|-----------|----------|
|12|2          |25        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|13|12         |4         |
|--|-----------|----------|
|14|8          |11        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|15|5          |27        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|16|26         |22        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|17|16         |26        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|18|29         |19        |
|--|-----------|----------|
|19|4          |1         |
|--|-----------|----------|
|20|9          |26        |
```

Now I struggle to create a corresponding SQL command or to determine the next steps.

I use SQL Server but every other SQL database or Excel would be fine to solve it.

**Edit:**

**Expected Result:**
list of n materials, where as many material lists of the products as possible are completely covered . The material list of each product is the `Table_test` table

n= variable input

If I want to make as many different products as possible from 3 materials, I give as input the number 3 and as output i get the 3 materials , with which I make a maximum of different products

With these materials from the result i can determine the Products in a second SQL as parameter, like this :

```
SELECT REFProduct FROM Table_test where REFMaterialin ([ResultList of materials])
```

**Edit 2
Excepted Output:**

```
|REFMaterial|
|-----------|
|6          |
|-----------|
|5          |
|-----------|
|24         |
|-----------|
```

Comment: Its not clear what you question is. Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: this part of question is not clear: `list of n materials, where as many material lists of the products as possible are completely covered`. Say, if I give 3 materials, how do you want to pick up products ?

Comment: i see, i think i have not thought it through to the end Edited a small addition

Comment: We need to see you actual expected results, not a text description of them.

Comment: have I expressed myself too misleadingly? 
Thanks for the comment I am quite new here